# What is the power of : a set of all compact connected sets with a smooth finite border on a plane?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We take plane and equip it with usual topology. Now we create an empty MainSet. Then we include all compact single-connected sets with a smooth finite border on this plane in the MainSet.

What would be the power of the construct?

Is it the power of continuum or or 2^continuum (like set of all functions) or something else?

---

Update. The number of elements in the MainSet is equal to the number of distinct borders of the elements. Each border is a closed curve and can be split in upper and lower part both of them are functions.From each pair of smooth functions I can build a border and turn it into an element of MainSet. Seems like MainSet has the same power as functions^2 = functions > continuum.
Which of my requirements reduce the size of the set to continuum? is it the border smoothness or compactness?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least continuum many because the unit closed disks with any center are in your set.  There are at most continuum many because the plane has a countable base and all open sets are unions of some set of base elements.  There are only continuum many subsets of the base.  The closed sets are the complements of the open sets, so there are at most continuum many closed sets.  The compact sets are a subset of the closed sets.  The compact sets with a smooth finite border are a subset of the compact sets.

Comment: As I understand it the MainSet MainSet is set containing all sets satisfying condition (compactness, smooth border,...) as members. It must have at least the power of continuum because a set of all unit circles on a plane has the power of continuum.

Comment: Does it mean that a set of all functions (2^continuum) is larger than a set of all "compact single connected sets with smooth border on a plane". See my updated question.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Having the set be compact requires that the border be continuous.  There are only continuum many continuous functions because you only need to specify their values at the (countably many) rationals, then can find the value at the irrationals by continuity.